# Function keeps returning true, cant find mistake?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

I need to write a function that will take two arrays and their size and then compare if the cells were equal.
If the cells were equal it will have to return true if not false.
However i cant seem to find my mistake, it keeps returning true.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool XArray(int a[],int b[],int sizeofA,int sizeofB, bool& v)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeofA && i <= sizeofB;i++)
    {  
         if (a[i]==b[i])
         {
                return v;
                continue;
         }
        else
        {
                v = false;
                 break;
        }
    }
    return v;         
} 


int main()
{   
    bool x = true;
    int a[3] = {1,2,3,};
    int b[3] = {1,2,7};
    XArray(a,b,3,3,x);
    cout << x << endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when debugging your code line by line?

Comment: Have you tried some input like `int a[3] = {1,2,3}; int b[3] = {2,3,4};`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should care about not having equal sized arrays, you might want
   to say false in that case
2. If you don't use the return type of the function, specify its return
   type as `void`.
3. You could handle it with one comparison within the for loop.
4. Another big problem is using operator `<=` with operand `sizeofA`. You should use the operator `<`, otherwise you go out of the array's scope which might yields you program to crash.

Please investigate the following code.

```
void XArray(int a[],int b[],int sizeofA,int sizeofB, bool& v)
{   
    v= true;
    if( sizeofA != sizeofB ){
        v=false;
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofA; i++){
            if (a[i] != b[i]){
                v= false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** I think this function should return `bool` and don't need to take the last parameter v. You can try to do it on your own as an exercise.

Comment: you are right i dont need to have bool as a parameter but then how can i return it? slightly confused

Comment: Remove the parameter `v`, then return either `true` or `false` whenever you are sure that those arrays are the same or not. Assign the result of the function to the variable `x` in the main, like this `x = XArray(a,b,3,3)`;

Comment: Then i will have to change the function to int not void so i can have a return right? And i am slightly confused with assigning the result to what will it do?

Comment: You can return false where we assigned false to v and return true at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to debug the code line by line. As it appears you are new to coding, here is the point you should pay attention about to solve the problem:

Where you are comparing a[i] with b[i] (a[i]==b[i]) you are returning 'v'. But you should do nothing in this block. Because you need to wait to check all the array elements, before returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return if(a[i] == b[i]). That way function returns after finding first equal pair. Instead iterate over every pair of cells and return if they are not equal. After iterating over everything return true. You can check if sizes are also equal. If not then you know for sure that arrays aren't equal. You also don't need bool reference.

Comment: i removed the return v; from the first if statement and now it seems to work, is that what you ment?

Comment: Yes. Btw, do you really need v argument there? Seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are trying to do this:

```
bool XArray(int a[],int b[],int sizeofA,int sizeofB, bool& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofA && i < sizeofB; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]!=b[i]) return false;
    }
    return v;
}
```